# UIAlertView : compare titles

Tags: ios, uialertview

I created a Alertview with login and password field.  If the user entered the wrong password I show another Alertview telling him to try again.

I would like to use the same code for both Alertviews.  Everything works fine if I am using just one title to compare.

What is wrong with this :

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if ([[actionSheet.title compare:@"Enter your login data"] == NSOrderedSame] ||
        [[actionSheet.title compare:@"Auth Error - Try again"] == NSOrderedSame])
    {
        // Do something
```

Basically: In both cases ( both titles ) I would like to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set same integer value for `tag` property for both the alert view and you can work with that.
e.g.

```
if (actionSheet.tag==25)
{
// Do your thing
}
```

if you still want to compare the titles you can use `- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString` method of `NSString` it will return success based on the comparison.

e.g.

```
if ([actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Enter your login data"] ||
    [actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Auth Error - Try again"])
{
    // Do your thing
}
```

HTH.